# Java Swing : why must resize frame, so that can show components have added

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jscrollpane

I have a simple Swing GUI. (and not only this, all swing GUI I have written). When run it, it doesn't show anything except blank screen, until I resize the main frame, so every components have painted again, and I can show them.

Here is my simple code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScroll Pane Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        JTextArea txtNotes = new JTextArea();
        txtNotes.setText("Hello World");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtNotes);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
}
```

So, my question is : how can when I start this class, the frame will appear all components I have added, not until I resize frame.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Do not add components to `JFrame` after the `JFrame` is visible (`setVisible(true)`)
- Not really good practice to call `setSize()` on frame rather call `pack()` (Causes `JFrame` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents) and let `LayoutManager` handle the size.
- Use [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (Event-Dispatch-Thread)
- call `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` as said by  @Gilbert Le Blanc (+1 to him) or else your EDT/Initial thread will remain active even after `JFrame` has been *closed*

Like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create GUI on EDT Thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                  JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScroll Pane Test");
                  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

                  JTextArea txtNotes = new JTextArea();
                  txtNotes.setText("Hello World");
                  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtNotes);
                  frame.add(scrollPane);//add components

                  frame.pack();
                  frame.setVisible(true);//show (after adding components)
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I think you meant "do not add components to frame after the frame is visible"

Comment: Thanks alot @DavidKroukamp for this help

Answer (score 5):

Your simple code is missing a few things.

You have to invoke `SwingUtilities` to put the Swing components on the event dispatch thread.

You should call the `setDefaultCloseOperation` on the `JFrame`.

You have to call the `JFrame` methods in the correct order.  The `setSize` or `pack` method is called, then the `setVisible` method is called last.

```
public class SimpleFrame implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScroll Pane Test");

        JTextArea txtNotes = new JTextArea();
        txtNotes.setText("Hello World");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtNotes);
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleFrame());
    }

}
```